# How to use the same user login on app and website with Firebase

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have a web application which uses Firebase authentication and in some cases user is redirected to a website (hosting) that uses the same proccess for authentication.

My doubt is: is there a way to use the same user login from app to website? Because now, user has to authenticate twice, on app and website and it's not good for their experience.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the app and the website, using the same project(in console)?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, both the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an idea:

Make that redirect parts a WebView and then pass data from the app to the web view.
Ithe web view uses that data. You can put the user token here and authenticate in that way.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried to do it but how can I authenticate user using UID? Is there any method? Because I couldn't find it.

Comment: You can usea the Custom Token authentication function of the Firebase-Admin SDK. IF you use the free firebase hosting service, you can use that like a Cloud Functions in the same hosting.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try it, and I'll let you know as soon as possible. Thank you!

Comment: did this work? Can you give an explanation of what you did? @Erasmo Neto